# In the documentclass exam how can I control the indenting of a question

Tags: exam

I used qformat to get the question to be formatted as I want, however I can't get "Question" to be flush on the left margin like previous paragraphs. I have included the code and an image of what the output looks like. What I really want is for the Q in Question to be directly underneath A for Allow.
Can anyone help with this?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
 \qformat{\textbf{\quad Question \thequestion. (Marks \totalpoints)\hfill} }
 {\huge\textbf{Section II}}

 {\large\textbf{Attempt All Questions}
        
\textbf{Allow about 45 Minutes for these questions}\newline}

%\newgeometry{left=0.5cm}
\begin{questions}
   

%\fillwithlines{2cm}
\question What is the time

\question[3]
Whas is the color of the ocean


\question[3]
What is the color of the sky

\fillwithlines{2cm}
\singlespacing
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The sort of layout I am after.
[image]

Comment: Remove the `\quad` before `Question`.

Comment: See the answer below. You can do this with `quenstionshook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. You should use `\renewcommand{\questionshook}` and change the left margin. There is more information in the manual section 4.4.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\begin{document}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion. (Marks \totalpoints)}\hfill}
 
{\huge\textbf{Section II}}

{\large\textbf{Attempt All Questions}
        
\textbf{Allow about 45 Minutes for these questions}\newline}

\begin{questions}
\question What is the time

\question[3]
Whas is the color of the ocean


\question[3]
What is the color of the sky

\fillwithlines{2cm}
\singlespacing
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]