# Code in examdoclass, how to correct the sections?

Tags: sectioning, exam

Does anyone know how to improve this code so that both of these sections are on the same line? I know it's because one of them is in the question part. But does anyone have an idea how to change it so that the numbering of questions under the problems section was continued? [image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\textbf{\thesection.\arabic{question}}}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Exercises}
\begin{questions}
\question this is exercise 1
\question this is exercise 2
\question this is exercise 3

\subsection{Problems}
\question this is problem 1
\question this is problem 2
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\questionshook` to align the sections and questions, and you can reset the question counter before a new subsection. Here it is:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\textbf{\thesection.\arabic{question}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Exercises}
\question this is exercise 1
\question this is exercise 2
\question this is exercise 3

\setcounter{question}{0}
\subsection{Problems}
\question this is problem 1
\question this is problem 2
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This answer is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678302/115089) one.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I need :D